# Get Chrome tab pid from Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, pid

I'm trying to get the process id associated with current tab thru chrome extension.

I did manage to get it thru `chrome.processes` experimental API.

There is any way to get the tab pid with standard (non-experimental) API ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get the real process ID (i.e. one that can be used by other programs to identify processes), then your only option is [`chrome.processes`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes), but this API is only available on the [Dev channel](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) (so not for Chrome stable nor Beta).

If you just need an identifier to uniquely identify processes, then you can get the "process ID of a tab" via the [`chrome.webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) API. This ID is only meaningful within Chrome. Before I delve into the details, let's first say that multiple tabs can share the same process ID, and that one tab can contain multiple processes (when the [Site isolation project](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/site-isolation) is enabled).

So, by "tab PID", I assume that you're referring to the process that hosts the top-level frame. Then you can retrieve a list of frames and extract the process ID for the tab as follows:

background.js

```js
'use strict';
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames({
        tabId: tab.id,
    }, function(details) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            alert('Error: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            return;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < details.length; ++i) {
            var frame = details[i];
            // The top-level frame has frame ID 0.
            if (frame.frameId === 0) {
                alert('Tab info:\n' +
                      'PID: ' + frame.processId + '\n' +
                      'URL: ' + frame.url);
                return; // There is only one frame with ID 0.
            }
        }
        alert('The top-level frame was not found!');
    });
});
```

manifest.json

```js
{
    "name": "Show tab PID",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Show tab PID"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webNavigation"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the operation system PID for use outside of chrome.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no other way except experimental API [chrome.processes](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes)